# I Don't know how to delete values using angular7

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, loopback

I'm using angular7 with loopback API. I want make delete code in tables. Can you suggest me.

But I tried some code it's not working. I have attached my code here..

**file.component.html**

```
    <td><button class="btn btn-success" (click)="deleteUser(user)"> Delete</button></td>
```

**file.component.ts**

```
   deleteUser(user: User): void {
this.apiService.deleteUser(user.id);
 };
```

**api.service.ts**

```
deleteUser(id: number): Observable<ApiResponse> {
return this.http.delete<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrl + id);
}
```

Also give me all the operation codes like **update** **delete**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you didn't subscribe, so the request didn't go out.

```
deleteUser(user: User): void {
   this.apiService.deleteUser(user.id).subscribe();
};
```